# Структура большого React проекта

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Интересует вопрос касательно структуры файлов в React проектах.

Если будет существовать проект в котором есть несколько активных страниц, к примеру как в соц.сетях. Моя страница, страница друга, страница со списком друзей и т.д.. Вопрос: какая структура файлов будет у подобного проекта?

Получается 1 страница это 1 компонент, а все они отображаются в App.js? 
(В данном случае привожу пример работы уже с существующей структурой проекта созданой create react app)

И в зависимости от состояния компонента App отображать ту или иную страницу, верно?

Мне же не прийдется под каждую отдельную страницу создавать отдельный React проект? Весь огромный сервис в одном html файле куда импортируется JSX код в , если я правильно все понимаю.

Comment: прочтите очень внимательно про реакт и что такое компоненты.

Comment: Все, не надо. Узнал про роутинг в реакте)

Answer (score 2):

реакт-роутер-4 поможет в создании SPA))^^', ну и матчасть, что такое роутинг и что такое компоненты неплохо бы знать